# Curl Error,displaying webpage ,not result

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, curl

Am a bit new to php.I found a way to use curl and display a webpage in another.its working fine.But there is a search function on original page.When  I search through the page it dosent giving any result.

the website am talking is 
http://bit.ly/1jhLxMm      Note : Shortened URL for privacy of original site

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://the-site-i-meationed-above.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = preg_replace("/Powered By/",'', $result);
echo $result
?>
```

I tried with iframe and everything is working perfect.But i dont wanna use iframe and do it completely in curl.I hope someone can help me.Thanks

Comment: Howard give a valid example of using another site's html form and adding `$result = preg_replace("/Powered By/",'', $result);`. I stated my reason to give the op a way to reverse it (by explaining their use  case and confirming the have Permission to do so).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a syntax error. How do you expect it to run? Put semicolon at where you are printing the result:

```
echo $result;
            ^--- can you see this??
```

Also add this one to handle redirection if you are using `bit.ly/` link directly:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

Comment: tested still no result :(                                                    new source :<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://the-site-i-meationed-above.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = preg_replace("/Powered By/",'', $result);
echo $result;
?>

Comment: @ArunGreen add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);` and show us what it outputs?

Comment: @ArunGreen `verbose` is not for output. it will print curl's debug msg on log or screen. you have to provide that if you want your answer. otherwise i can't help.

Comment: `* About to connect() to fast2sms.com port 80 (#0) * Trying 192.3.149.121... * connected * Connected to fast2sms.com (192.3.149.121) port 80 (#0) > GET /tracker.php HTTP/1.1 Host: fast2sms.com Accept: */* < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Sun, 23 Mar 2014 09:08:20 GMT < Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635`

Comment: `< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.23 < Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT < Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 < Pragma: no-cache < Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=0bbcb792ce3392a5f6a34967796e9547; path=/ < Transfer-Encoding: chunked < Content-Type: text/html < * Connection #0 to host fast2sms.com left intact * Closing connection #0`

Comment: @ArunGreen your response says `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` which implies that curl successfully perform its task. Probably they way you are running or checking your code has a flaw!